# Kafka Streams Running out of memory on nodes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running a kafka streams application on a node and it runs out of memory for an application,
I want to run kafka streams application on cluster level

How can I accomplish the same, as the stateful stream processing stores the in local, even if I run two set of instances of same application and set state.dir for kafka streams a common location, how can I share the load of the application with another instance in stateful streaming scenario?

I tried running count aggregation application in two instances but it ended up in splitting the stateful data and messing up the expected result

Comment: Need more details. What JVM options are you running your code with? What types of profiling have you done for your code to identify what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

One instance per topic partition is highly recommend to distribute the load, separately from increasing your app heap size.

> how can I share the load of the application with another instance

This is automatic. The Kafka protocol handles this for you

> ended up in splitting the stateful data

This is expected. To query the state of all instances, there is documentation for that. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html